# A weird function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider this function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$: 
$$f(x):= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
        (-1)^m\cdot 2^n & \text{for $x=\frac{2m+1}{2^n}$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $m\in\mathbb{Z}$,}\\
        0 & \text{otherwise.} 
        \end{array}\right.
$$
Then, it is easy to show that
for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, with $a<b$, we have 
$$\inf_{x\in (a,b)} f(x)=-\infty\quad\mbox{and} \sup_{x\in (a,b)} f(x)=+\infty.$$

My question (for which I do not have an answer) is about a stronger property.

> Is there a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, with $a<b$, then $f((a,b))$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Any related references will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Take an Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ as a $\mathbb Q$ vector space. Write your basis $(b_i)_{i \in \mathbb R}$ and pick a special $b_j$. Now, let $\pi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb Qb_j \subset \mathbb R$ be the projection.

The graph of $\pi$ is dense in $\mathbb R^2$ so in particular your property is verified.

Notice that $\pi$ looks strange but it is $\mathbb Q$-linear and periodic ! (And in fact, it has lot of periods : any $\mathbb Q$-linear combinaison of the $(b_i)_{i \in \mathbb R, i \neq j}$ will be a period for $\pi$ by definition)

Comment: Well maybe "$\mathbb{Q}$ - linear" is more accurate. People who have seen this before will know what you mean, but it is misleading to describe it as a 'linear' function when it is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ as this suggests that it distributes over a linear combination the way a linear function usually does, i.e. the additional property $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$ for all scalar $\lambda$.

Comment: I though it was obvious, because else $f$ would be the identity. But I think you're right and I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 8):

Yes: the [Conway base-13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function). Under this function, the image of every nonempty open interval of $\Bbb R$ is not only dense in $\Bbb R$ but also the whole of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

This is based on Problem 113 in A. Shen & N. K. Vereshchagin, *Basic Set Theory* (AMS, 2002):

If $f$ is the function constructed in [N.H.'s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1895944/213690), it satisfies the condition
$$
f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) \text{ for all } x, y \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Any function satisfying this condition also satisfies $f(nx) = nf(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. (In particular, $f(0) = 0$.) Therefore,
$f(qx) = qf(x)$ for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$; that is, $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear.

On the other hand, the constructed $f$ is a non-zero function which assumes only
countably many values, so it cannot satisfy the condition $f(r) = rf(1)$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$; therefore $f$ is not $\mathbb{R}$-linear.

Now let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be *any* function that is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear but not $\mathbb{R}$-linear.

If $f$ were continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, it would be $\mathbb{R}$-linear.

If $f$ were continuous at $0$, it would be continuous everywhere.

So, $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

This implies that $f$ is unbounded in every open neighbourhood of $0$.

> **Proof:** Suppose, on the contrary, that there existed $A > 0$, $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \leqslant A$ for all $x$ such that $|x| < \delta$.
>
> [Incidentally, is it
>   acceptable to write this phrase as "for all $|x| < \delta$"?]
>
> Then for every positive integer $n$ we would have $|f(x)| = |f(nx)|/n \leqslant A/n$ for all $x$ such that $|x| < \delta/n$. This would imply that $f$ is continuous at $0$, contrary to what has been established.

For all $\delta > 0$, because $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear, $f((-\delta, \delta))$ is not only unbounded but also dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

> **Proof:** Any finite open interval $V \subset \mathbb{R}$ is contained in $(-|f(x)|, |f(x)|)$ for some $x$ such that $|x| < \delta$. Then
>   $$
> f((-\delta, \delta)) \supseteq
> f(\{qx : q \in \mathbb{Q},\ |q| < 1\}) =
> \{qf(x) : q \in \mathbb{Q},\ |q| < 1\},
> $$
>   and this set is dense in $(-|f(x)|, |f(x)|)$, therefore it intersects $V$, as required.

For all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < b$,
$$
f((a, b)) = \left\{
f\left(\frac{a + b}{2}\right) + y :
y \in f\left(\left(\frac{a - b}{2}, \frac{b - a}{2}\right)\right)
\right\},
$$
and this is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Regarding your question "Incidentally, is it acceptable to write this phrase as "for all $|x|<δ$"?": No. If you want a short way to say "for all $x$ such that $|x|<δ$",  it can be condensed to "for $|x|<δ$". This is grammatically and logically adequate, albeit a little laconic. Another way of putting it, which I prefer and which carries the force of "all", is "whenever $|x|<δ$".